# How to unselect / unhighlight selected and highlighted text in QScintilla editor widget?

Tags: c++, qt5, qscintilla

I'm trying to write a search box, containing find/find previous/find next to interact with a QScintilla textEditor widget. I therefore wrote to methods, one for highlighting all matching words and then select first occurance, one for unselecting/unhighlighting them.

First run seams to do as it should, but if I repeat the search with another keyword, both the old and the new keyword are shown.

[image]

Here's my code fragment:

```
//
// search & replace:
// do_search_and_replace() - search for matching word
//
void MainWindow::do_search_and_replace(QString action_str)
{
    int line, index;
    qDebug() <<  "do_search_and_replace()";
    // just to be sure...
    if(action_str.isEmpty())
        action_str == "0";

    int action_nr = action_str.toInt();    // convert argument to int, so we can switch() on it...
    text = ui->lineEdit_find->text();
    docText = ui->textEdit->text();
    qDebug() <<  "action_nr: " << action_nr;

    //
    // first part: Mark all occurances of search term
    //
    if (!( text.isEmpty() ))
    {
        qDebug() << text;
        ui->textEdit->SendScintilla(QsciScintillaBase::SCI_INDICSETSTYLE, 0, QsciScintilla::INDIC_FULLBOX);
        ui->textEdit->SendScintilla(QsciScintillaBase::SCI_INDICSETFORE,0, QColor(Qt::darkBlue));


        int end = docText.lastIndexOf(text);
        int cur = -1;

        if(end != -1)
        {
            ui->textEdit->getCursorPosition(&line, &index);
            qDebug() << "line: " << line << " index: " << index;
            while(cur != end)
            {
                cur = docText.indexOf(text,cur+1);
                ui->textEdit->SendScintilla(QsciScintillaBase::SCI_INDICATORFILLRANGE,cur,
                    text.length());
            }
        }
    } // END text.isEmpty(), END mark ALL

    //
    // second part: Find firs occurance of search term
    //
    bool use_regular_expression, is_case_sensitive, match_whole_word_only, use_wrap, search_forward;
    use_regular_expression = false;
    is_case_sensitive = ui->checkBox_CaseSensitive->isChecked();
    match_whole_word_only = ui->checkBox_WholeWords->isChecked();
    use_wrap = true;
    search_forward = ui->radioButton_Forward->isChecked();

    ui->textEdit->SendScintilla(QsciScintillaBase::SCI_INDICSETSTYLE, 0, QsciScintilla::INDIC_FULLBOX);
    //ui->textEdit->SendScintilla(QsciScintillaBase::SCI_INDICSETFORE,0, QColor(Qt::darkBlue));

    bool found = ui->textEdit->findFirst(text, use_regular_expression, is_case_sensitive, match_whole_word_only, use_wrap, search_forward);
    qDebug() <<  "START: found = " << found;
    while(found)
    {
        ui->textEdit->getCursorPosition(&line, &index);

        qDebug() << "line: " << line << " index: " << index;
        qDebug() << text;

        // pattern: found = findFirst(pattern, use_regular_expression, is_case_sensitive, match_whole_word_only, use_wrap, search_forward)
        //found = ui->textEdit->findFirst(text, use_regular_expression, is_case_sensitive, match_whole_word_only, use_wrap, search_forward);

        if(found)
        {
            ui->textEdit->SendScintilla(QsciScintillaBase::SCI_INDICATORFILLRANGE, line, text.length());
            int start = ui->textEdit->positionFromLineIndex(line, index);
            int end = ui->textEdit->positionFromLineIndex(line, index + text.length());
            qDebug() << "line: " << line << " start: " << start << " end: " << end;

//            found = ui->textEdit->findNext();
//            ui->textEdit->SendScintilla(QsciScintillaBase::SCI_INDICATORFILLRANGE, line, text.length());

        }

        found = false;
    }
}


//
// unselect selected stuff
//
void MainWindow::reset_searchResult()
{
    int line, index;
    qDebug() <<  "in: reset_searchResult()";

    //QString text = ui->lineEdit_find->text();
    text.clear();
    docText.clear();

    //
    // first part: Mark all occurances of search term
    //
    if (( text.isEmpty() ))
    {
        qDebug() << text;
        ui->textEdit->SendScintilla(QsciScintillaBase::SCI_INDICSETSTYLE, 0, QsciScintilla::INDIC_PLAIN);
        ui->textEdit->SendScintilla(QsciScintillaBase::SCI_INDICSETFORE,0, QColor(Qt::white));

        //docText = text;
        docText = ui->lineEdit_find->text();
        int end = docText.lastIndexOf(text);
        int cur = -1;

        if(end != -1)
        {
            ui->textEdit->getCursorPosition(&line, &index);
            qDebug() << "line: " << line << " index: " << index;
            while(cur != end)
            {
                cur = docText.indexOf(text,cur+1);
                ui->textEdit->SendScintilla(QsciScintillaBase::SCI_INDICATORALLONFOR,cur, text.length());
                ui->textEdit->SendScintilla(QsciScintillaBase::SCI_INDICATORCLEARRANGE,cur, text.length());
            }
        }
    } // END text.isEmpty(), END mark ALL

    //
    // second part: Find firs occurance of search term
    //
    bool use_regular_expression, is_case_sensitive, match_whole_word_only, use_wrap, search_forward;
    use_regular_expression = false;
    is_case_sensitive = ui->checkBox_CaseSensitive->isChecked();
    match_whole_word_only = ui->checkBox_WholeWords->isChecked();
    use_wrap = true;
    search_forward = ui->radioButton_Forward->isChecked();

    ui->textEdit->SendScintilla(QsciScintillaBase::SCI_INDICSETSTYLE, 0, QsciScintilla::INDIC_PLAIN);
    //ui->textEdit->SendScintilla(QsciScintillaBase::SCI_INDICSETFORE,0, QColor(Qt::darkBlue));

    bool found = ui->textEdit->findFirst(text, use_regular_expression, is_case_sensitive, match_whole_word_only, use_wrap, search_forward);
    qDebug() <<  "START: found = " << found;
    while(found)
    {
        ui->textEdit->getCursorPosition(&line, &index);

        if(found)
        {
            ui->textEdit->SendScintilla(QsciScintillaBase::SCI_INDICATORCLEARRANGE, line, text.length());
            int start = ui->textEdit->positionFromLineIndex(line, index);
            int end = ui->textEdit->positionFromLineIndex(line, index + text.length());
            qDebug() << "line: " << line << " start: " << start << " end: " << end;

        }

        found = false;
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure this isn't the best code ever written, but all I can afford... ;)

Maybe someone who is fit with QScintilla can correct my attempts or provide me with a working search & highlight example that can be called multiple times without keeping the old results?

Thanks in advance, people!

Comment: You would clear the old markers before doing a new search?

Comment: Yes - that's what I'm trying to do in the second method! Do you have some advice on how to clear the old markers correctly, @tungIt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it's easier than you think, assume that you used `QsciScintilla`  instance for your ui->textEdit :

```
#define MY_MARKER_ID 0

void MainWindow::clearMarkers()
{
    int lastLine = ui->textEdit->lines() - 1;
    ui->textEdit->clearIndicatorRange( 0, 0, lastLine, ui->textEdit->text( lastLine ).length() - 1, MY_MARKER_ID );
}
```

Comment: @tungIt: Indeed! Hughe thanks for that, you saved me again on QScintilla. I slightly remember that, while trying to find any docs that help me further, I stumbled over Jaco Lusser's Scintilla docs and there was said that a marker id should be above 7, since 0 to 7 are allready reserved. Was a hint, but I couldn't realize how to work with it... ;)

Comment: @MichaelBergmann: you are welcome. If you want to go along with QScintilla, let's see a project that used it [QGIS](https://qgis.org/api/qgsexpressionbuilderwidget_8cpp_source.html)